# Discrete time process vs Markov chain.

Tags: measure-theory, markov-chains

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a discrete time process, which takes values in $S$ that is finite or countable. I want to prove that there exists a Markov chain $Y_1,Y_2...$ taking values in countable $\hat S$, and a function $f:\hat S \rightarrow S$ such that $f(Y_n)=X_n$ for any $n$.

How to prove this? It seems untrue as the discrete time process can depend on the past values, while the Markov process only depends on the last value.

Comment: What is $\hat{S}$?

Comment: @user10354138 it's the set that the markov chain takes values in.

Comment: In case I'm allowed to be pretend to be a lawyer and use the fact that you have not explicitly put any assumptions on $\hat S$, I'd take $\hat S = S^{\Bbb N}$, i.e. the space of all infinite histories of $X$.  Otherwise indeed, there may not exist such a Markov Chain.

Comment: @Ilya It has to be countable unfortunately. Doesn't work when $S$ is infinite.

Comment: Well, maybe then one could work around with $\hat S = \bigcup_{n\in \Bbb N}S^n$, which is countable